# Is it valid to have non-query text after query string in URL?

Tags: url

I am having issues parsing this url:

`http://HOST/PATH?foo=bar/PATH2`

So, is it valid to append PATH2 after the query string in the URL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/` in that URL is not "after" the query-string, it is *part of* the query string, and this is perfectly valid.

RFC 3986 (Generic URI Syntax) [states in section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4):

> The query component is indicated by the first question
> mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
> or by the end of the URI.

It goes on to explicitly mention `/` as valid in the query:

> The characters slash ("/") and question mark ("?") may represent data
> within the query component.

More specifically, this query string is in the common `key=value` format, so `?foo=bar/PATH2` should be read as "there is a key `foo` with a value `bar/PATH2`".

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes sense